# Acceso denegado " failed to register layer: ..." Docker 1.12.3 on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows10, docker, docker-compose

Estoy intentando crear contenedores de docker en un Windows 10, pero siempre me da el siguiente error de:

> "failed to register layer: rename C:....."

No encuentro ningún hilo que lo explique

Os pongo la traza del pull:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from microsoft/aspnet

9c7f9c7d9bc2: Pull complete
d33fff6043a1: Pull complete
b7c3bbe47489: Extracting [==================================================>] 123.8 MB/123.8 MB
1028e286eae2: Download complete
28e6f26ee039: Download complete
a0db4e322336: Download complete
failed to register layer: rename C:\ProgramData\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\tmp\write-set-255580435 C:\ProgramDat
a\Docker\image\windowsfilter\layerdb\sha256\b01351fac2d37b162190ef8dde977bbf009d8e3fa2446dd71595b142b73d28a3: Acceso den
egado.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay un issue muy similar a lo que comentas, se puede ver que en este post ha sido solucionado:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/292

El usuario dheater cuenta su experiencia y como lo solucionó, en este caso se debía a al antivirus (McAfee) que dificulta el acceso. Espero que este sea tu caso y que se pueda solucionar.